# Как добраться до слушателя в адаптере?

Tags: java, android

Есть ListView lvMain для которого есть адаптер ThAdapter.

```
lvMain.setAdapter(th_adpt);
lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        }
    });
```

Каждая строка ListView содержит layout с несколькими CheckBox (cb1,cb2,cb3)
Как "слушать" эти чекбоксы?

Comment: Лучше слушать их в самом адаптере

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        int i = порядковый номер чекбокса от нуля;
        ((ViewGroup)view).getChildat(i);
    }
});
```

Upd
Если у вас `onItemClick()` срабатывает при нажатии на `Layout` или любой другой `ViewGroup`, только тогда можно как в примере выше преобразовать его к `(GroupView)`. У класса `GroupView` есть массив всех вьюх из этого лайота, упорядоченых согласно порядку их обьвления в xml файле(сверху вниз), или как вы их добавляли в коде. Получить таким образом вью можно методом `getChildAt(int)` который сам из массива Вьюх возвращает по указанному индексу

Comment: p.s такой код будет работать если внутри только 3 чекбокса и нету доп вью или контейнеров.